# Como pasar datos de un estado a otro componente (ferch a componente)

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-hooks

### no puedo pasar los datos de mi estado a un componente hijo

al intentar pasar datos a un componente, el estado se cambia a un objeto vacio

```
const [alumno, setAlumno] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    traerUsuario(curp).then(response => {
        setAlumno(response);
    });
}, [])
console.log(alumno)//aqui el console.log no funciona, de igual manera el estado queda vacio

return(
   //genera el error de igual manera ya que el estado esta vacio
    <div>{alumno.aceptado ? <Aceptado alumno={alumno} /> : <Rechazado alumno={alumno} />}</div>
)
```

}

pero al cambiar el return por esto e intentar renderizarlo directamente todo sucede con normalidad

```
    return(
        <div>{alumno.nombre }</div>//renderiza el nombre con normalidad
    )
```

saben que estare obviando? de antemano gracias

Comment: Cuando inicias el componente (o la App), el console.log que esta en tu outter scope, **debe pintarse 2 veces**, la primera vez estará vacío por la configuración que le diste al hook **useState**, pero la segunda vez debería traer el resultado de la asignación a **setAlumno** después de la operación asincrónica, puedes verificar y confirmar esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pareciera ser que el problema es que tu function `traerUsuario()` es asincrónica, por lo tanto a la hora de renderizar el objeto la promesa de la función no se ha resuelto y el valor de `alumno` es el que definiste en `useState()` que es un objeto vacío `{}`, podrías intentar algo así:

```
const [alumno, setAlumno] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    if(alumno ==={}){
        traerUsuario(curp).then(response => {
        setAlumno(response);
      });
    }
}, [alumno])

const alumnoMarkup = ()=>(
  (alumno==={})
  ?
  (<div> Cargando alumno, por favor espere...</div>)
  :
  (<div>{alumno.aceptado ? <Aceptado alumno={alumno} /> : <Rechazado alumno={alumno}/></div>)
);

return(
  {alumnoMarkup()}
)
```